# Implementing responder action in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsmenuitem, responder-chain

I am having difficulty implementing an action for an NSMenuItem in Swift. Normally, you implement the action like this in Objective-C:

```
- (void) asdf:(id)sender
```

This works perfectly fine, after setting up the action in the first responder like so:

[image: user defined first responder]

However, after rewriting my view controller in Swift, the following new method doesn't seem to be called:

```
func asdf(sender: AnyObject?)
```

It doesn't seem to work, even though both the Obj-C and Swift versions are for the same view controller subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3.0 you'd define it as:

```
func asdf(_ sender: Any)
```

Why?

If you use `_` you can drop parameter name when calling a function, so now you can call it like:

```
object.asdf(object)
```

Instead of:

```
object.asdf(sender: object)
```

Moreover, with Swift you'd use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` in this context. You can find more on differences between those [here](http://kuczborski.com/2014/07/29/any-vs-anyobject/).